# How to check if the item has specific class so we don't print it in selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to check if the item in the page has this class ('ads__item') so we don't print it's content

```
ov_title = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('ads__item__ad--title')
ov_ads = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('ads__item')
time.sleep(1)

for item in ov_title:
    if driver.find_elements_by_class_name('') == ov_ads:
        just ignore it
    else:
        print(item.text)
```

Comment: For a canonical answer you need to update the question with the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_attribute()` method in selenium to get any attribute like id, class of a tag. Need to pass required attribute name in it e.g. `get_attribute('class')`

Use below code in your case to check whether an element has the intended class name

```
ov_title = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('ads__item__ad--title')
class_name = 'xyz'
time.sleep(1)

for item in ov_title:
    if item.get_attribute('class').contains(class_name):
        print('we are ignoring this')
    else:
        print(item.text)
```

Comment: I get this error   AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'contains'

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make something like this work with...

`if 'classname' in element.get_attribute('class')`